# How to debug in Jetty source code?

Tags: java, maven, debugging, jetty

I am assigned a project in which we attempt to push content from a Jetty server to one or more connected clients, using the SPDY protocol. Changes to the current pushing strategy and handlers are required, so I want to change the server's implementation and be able to debug the newly inserted code. I downloaded Jetty's source code from GitHub, and can use the `mvn clean install` command to generate a distribution in jetty-distribution/target/distribution.

To write my own server handlers en strategies, I loaded all Maven projects in NetBeans, and everything can be build from the top project down. I defined my own handlers, and by passing the right arguments in the project `Jetty-Start` (jetty home and base) and using the right XML configurations, I can start the server in debug mode from within Java. I can the debug the main class, but in the main, Jetty is executed in another JVM:

```
// execute Jetty in another JVM
if (args.isExec())
{
    CommandLineBuilder cmd = args.getMainArgs(baseHome,true);
    cmd.debug();
    ProcessBuilder pbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd.getArgs());
    StartLog.endStartLog();
    final Process process = pbuilder.start();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            StartLog.debug("Destroying " + process);
            process.destroy();
        }
    });

    copyInThread(process.getErrorStream(),System.err);
    copyInThread(process.getInputStream(),System.out);
    copyInThread(System.in,process.getOutputStream());
    process.waitFor();
    System.exit(0); // exit JVM when child process ends.
    return;
}
```

When accessing the server through the browser, no breakpoint in the server's code is ever triggered. I really need to be able to understand the flow from the request handlers to the pushing strategy, so how can I fully debug the server's implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some parameters into your JVM :Run jetty with this

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4000
```

than run remote and debug with this

```
-Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4000
```

Hope it will helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I looked into remote debugging, and I can start the server from command window using the following command: `java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8585,server=y,suspend=n -jar start.jar --module=spdy`. Inside NetBeans, I can add a debugger, listening at host localhost and port 8585 and NetBeans indeed goes in debug mode. However, still no breakpoint is triggered. Is there anything specific that needs to be handled here?

Comment: You change adress port from 4000 to 8585 but its not port of jetty. Its port of debug listener you should use 4000 or smth Imho.

Comment: I managed to make it work, by using your suggestion and using a similar approach to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205063/processbuilder-debugging. Thanks a lot!